# iso 8601 string to useable d3 date without using localtime timezone offset

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So i'm sitting in GMT+2.

```
d.x = '2018-07-01T00:00:00.000Z';
```

I'm trying to use this:

```
const line = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return d.y !== null; })
    .x(function(d) { 
        const time = d3.time.format.iso.parse(d.x); // <--- Mon Jul 1 2018 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
        return options.x.scale(time); 
    })
    .y(function(d) { 
        return options.y.scale(d.y); 
    });
```

This issue is when I use the d3 time format iso function it takes the utc string and forces it to use my local gmt+2 (Mon Jul 1 2018 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)). I need to avoid this.

How would I convert the iso 8601 timestamp so that I can use it with d3 lines?

Comment: Would you be willing to use external libraries?

Comment: I have the moment library which I can use)

Comment: Dates are always stored as GMT time and converted on display, Use the UTC versions of the d3-time module everywhere including the scales.

Comment: @rioV8 This is v3!

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using Moment, does this give you what you need?

```
moment.utc('2018-07-01T00:00:00.000Z').format('HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: This is towards what I need. However I need d3 to accept it! (with the date included. The timezone can be left out)

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

```
const parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %X").parse;
const time = parseDate(moment.utc(d.x).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
```